# 503 Error adding Custom Image to Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I've created and uploaded a custom ubuntu image to a Cloud Storage bucket. When I try to add the image to my project I am getting a 503 error. I'm not sure what I can do to debug this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "kind": "compute#image",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta16/projects/pan-cancer-pilot/global/images/ubuntu-12-04",
  "id": "16894190676133962953",
  "creationTimestamp": "2014-01-02T07:47:40.539-08:00",
  "name": "ubuntu-12-04",
  "description": "",
  "sourceType": "RAW",
  "rawDisk": {
    "containerType": "TAR",
    "source": ""
  },
  "status": "FAILED"
}

+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| name                | operation-1388677660294-4eefeb6a51678-4adcd88d           |
| region              |                                                          |
| zone                |                                                          |
| creation-time       |                                                          |
| status              | DONE                                                     |
| progress            | 100                                                      |
| status-message      |                                                          |
| target              | ubuntu-12-04                                             |
| target-id           | 16894190676133962953                                     |
| client-operation-id |                                                          |
| insert-time         | 2014-01-02T07:47:40.294-08:00                            |
| user                | llevar@gmail.com                                         |
| start-time          | 2014-01-02T07:47:40.375-08:00                            |
| end-time            | 2014-01-02T07:48:22.405-08:00                            |
| operation-type      | insert                                                   |
| error-code          | 503                                                      |
| error-message       | SERVICE UNAVAILABLE                                      |
| warning             |                                                          |
| warning-message     |                                                          |
| error               |                                                          |
|   error             | INTERNAL_ERROR                                           |
|   message           | Code: 'CgVJTUFHRRIZOTUzMjQ2MjAwNDA4LnVidW50dS0xMi0wNA==' |
| error               |                                                          |
|   error             | INTERNAL_ERROR                                           |
|   message           | Code: 'CgVJTUFHRRIZOTUzMjQ2MjAwNDA4LnVidW50dS0xMi0wNA==' |
| error               |                                                          |
|   error             | INTERNAL_ERROR                                           |
|   message           | Code: 'CgVJTUFHRRIZOTUzMjQ2MjAwNDA4LnVidW50dS0xMi0wNA==' |
| error               |                                                          |
|   error             | INTERNAL_ERROR                                           |
|   message           | Code: 'CgVJTUFHRRIZOTUzMjQ2MjAwNDA4LnVidW50dS0xMi0wNA==' |
| error               |                                                          |
|   error             | INTERNAL_ERROR                                           |
|   message           | Code: 'CgVJTUFHRRIZOTUzMjQ2MjAwNDA4LnVidW50dS0xMi0wNA==' |
| error               |                                                          |
|   error             | INTERNAL_ERROR                                           |
|   message           | Code: 'CgVJTUFHRRIZOTUzMjQ2MjAwNDA4LnVidW50dS0xMi0wNA==' |
+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: 503 Service Unavailable, it says. It looks like you're seeing a transient error. Try again later.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're still using v1beta16. Can you download the Cloud SDK and/or run "gcloud components update" to move it up to the v1 API?

There was an important change made to the way kernels are handled in the v1 API and you may be running into an issue related to that. Also, I suspect you want to use the kernel from your Custom Image and you'll want to use the v1 API to do that.

Full details about kernel changes are in the transition documents. https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/transition-v1